# Display folder sizes in file manager

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, filemanager

In nautilus (or nemo) file manager, the "Size" column shows the filesize for files and the number of items contained in a folder for subdirectories:

[image]

Number of items is not that important for me, it would be more useful if I could make this column show the total size contained under the directory.  I had an extension on windows called [foldersize](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) which shows what I mean:

[image]

I think it involved a service which ran in the background monitoring filesystem modifications in order to make sure the column was kept up to date.

I am interested to know if there is any similar extension to nautilus, I would also be open to switching to another file manager to get this functionality.  I am aware of the Disk Usage Analyser in Ubuntu, but what I'm looking for is a solution with file manager integration.

Comment: I know that nobody has answered your question, but i was wondering if you found something. I currently switch to Nemo, and the only extra info I get is a bar under the Filesystems that shows me how full they are, but nothing for a per folder basis.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet.  I am also using Nemo.

Comment: I've made a feature request for it: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/637

Comment: That nemo feature request was closed, with (as far as I can tell) no plan to implement it. 9 years on from this OP, is there still no Linux file manager that will show folder total content sizes? That's seems kind of incredible, given that MacOS has been doing it for over a decade...

Comment: @GlenWhitney Still don't have any solution to offer, unfortunately. I use `ncdu` in a terminal when I need this info. I'm still continuing to watch this question in hopes of new answers, even though I don't use Ubuntu any more.

Comment: dsz's answer put me on Double-Commander and a _lot_ of customization later, it's tolerable.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help as it's not exactly what you're looking for, but you can display the file size under the icon:

1. Open the file explorer
2. Go to places
3. Select preferences
4. Select display tab

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-tweak-nautilus-to-display-size-of-files-under-their-name.html

However, this is probably a more direct answer to your question: [Show current folder size in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101963/show-current-folder-size-in-nautilus)

Answer (score 1):

Always calculating the disk usage of a directory accurately (including hardlinks etc.) would slow you down, so it is not done. (With large directories I even have to wait quite a while to get the number of items.)

If you want to analyze disk usage try `gdmap` or `baobab`. There are even more tools.

Comment: I mentioned in my question already I'm aware of baobab (it's the same as Ubuntu disk usage analyzer) and I also have gdmap.  Neither of these can be integrated into the file manager.  Calculating the usage of a directory does not necessarily have to be slow, if you have a daemon which monitors filesystem changes and updates an index accordingly.  Similar to using `find` vs using `updatedb` and `locate`

Comment: Slowness is not an answer, and it's one of the simplest problems to solve.  Plus its a subject reference.

Answer (score 1):

I found **two** tools!

GUI: Double-Commander, will add the "deep" sizes if you hit `Alt+Shift+Enter`.  Unfortunately, it's not sticky, need to be done again when you change to another folder :-(

CLI only: `vfn`

`Alt+Z` configures it to show deep folder sizes; **AND** it's sticky!

It feels a little like `ncdu`, but with file management stuff too.

A little counter-intuative on the UI front to me, (`e` for erase (rather than a `d`elete), `h` for help; `?` launches a sub-shell), but it does the job.

`vfu` is the winner for me; I'll get used to the odd key-bindings!

Comment: Typo: on your first reference to `vfu` you mistakenly say `vfn`

Comment: I reluctantly use Double-Commander: it looks and behaves fairly clunky, and I turned off most of its cluttered UI, and made the second file view close to zero-width (usually not needed and apparently can't be closed -- I guess it feels it has to always live up to its name). Also I didn't like that the only "type" field it had was mime type, not a plain description, which led to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728346/most-thorough-way-to-determine-the-user-perspective-type-of-a-file-in-linux as I tried to make a WDX plugin for a plain-language file type.

Answer (score -1):

Krusader will calculate the size of one or directories. This is very useful when you are trying to figure out how much data you can fit on a a CD or DVD data archive disk.

Comment: Unhelpful answer.  Installed Krusader just for this, and no option anywhere to set this.  If it's possible, tell us how to, or you're not answering the question.

Comment: @dsz, you may find more info on this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/192609/how-to-get-the-size-for-all-subdirs-in-krusader